# Can Ubuntu run on Windows 8 tablet PCs and convertibles? (Dell XPS 12)

Tags: tablet, windows-8, hybrid, ultrabook

I was looking at some laptop/tablet hybrids, and I came across the [Dell XPS 12](http://www.dell.com/us/p/xps-12-l221x/pd?ST=%20dell%20%20xps%20%20duo%20%2012&dgc=ST&cid=254601&lid=4500109&acd=sQ2IOmnwt,30684705114,901pdb6671) (with an Intel CPU). It looked like a nice Ultrabook convertible, but (obviously) it runs Windows 8. Can Ubuntu run on any Ultrabook convertibles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of any reason that it shouldn't be able to. If the hardware meets the minimum requirements, there should be no problem. I'm not sure to what extent Ubuntu supports touch controls, though. So, you might want to install it alongside 8.

Comment: I wouldnt have ubuntu replace it, just in case its defective or something goes wrong. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

For the Surface, it's a definitive "no" for now. This is because Microsoft locked down their tablet (the ARM version anyway, not sure about the x86 one) so that no other OS can be installed (though, I'd give it some time before some people find a way).

Here's an [article](http://www.itworld.com/software/287946/there-will-be-no-easy-way-install-linux-windows-8-pcs) on the secure boot:

Comment: Thanks. Im not planning on getting that, though. My decision is either an ultrabook convertible (if it can run ubuntu, or course) or the 15" samsung series 9, if it is under $1000 on black friday/cyber monday

Comment: Ubuntu 12.10, I believe, has support for bypassing Windows 8 lockdown, believe it or not. Kubuntu does as well. I believe it is detailed here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QuantalQuetzal/ReleaseNotes/Kubuntu#QuantalQuetzal.2BAC8-ReleaseNotes.2BAC8-CommonInfrastructure.Secure_Boot

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, yes, it's possible.

Linux can run on ARM, x86-64, and several other microarchitectures.

With the right configuration and formatting, it's very possible to install and boot from Ubuntu on a Windows 8 made tablet.

I was considering providing a series of tutorials and articles for how to get Linux-based distros to boot on different hardware and microarchitecture platforms, etc.

Comment: Ubuntu came out with their [phone OS](http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/phone) and displayed it at CES. It sounds great, but I am wondering if it can actually act like a PC. I guess they are putting it on a tablet, too. You should make the series! I think a lot of people would use the video as a tutorial

Comment: Cool! Ubuntu is seriously going to dominate the Linux-based market for consumers, second to Android devices. I will do my best to work on the series soon!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be installed.
I've installed it on Lenovo Helix.

Unfortunately few drawbacks in Ubuntu 14.04: 
- Touch is supported, but there is no software keyboard - so you cannot type anything in, when undocking from hardware keyboard.
- No screen rotation support

All other things works well (at least for Helix)

Comment: Doesn't `onboard` work? http://askubuntu.com/questions/455336/on-screen-keyboard-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Comment: In my case it didn't work automatically. But is was a year ago.