# On-screen keyboard in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: vaio, touchscreen, onscreen-keyboard

Under Microsoft Windows 8, our Sony VAIO Tap 20 (a touch-screen desktop computer) automatically displays an on-screen keyboard if one touches a text field on-screen or there is otherwise no keyboard available (for example, the included bluetooth keyboard is switched-off or flat)... There is also a (notification area/system tray-based) option to display or hide the on-screen keyboard on-demand.

Does such functionality exist under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ("Trusty Tahr")?

My understanding is that Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ("Trusty Tahr") is supposed to be a mostly smartphone/tablet-focused upgrade... But for the life of me, I cannot find functionality that replicates that of Windows 8 (as described above)!

I've finally convinced the wife to let me single-boot Ubuntu on our VAIO Tap 20, but the included bluetooth keyboard smashes through batteries like they're going out of fashion, so until we can buy a corded keyboard, we need a solution (preferably built-in) that replicates the functionality found under Windows 8...

--

Never mind - all one needs to do after @Rmano 's solution is log-out and log back in... I should also note that this was already installed under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ("Trusty Tahr").

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The relevant program should be "onboard". You can install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install onboard
```

and launch it with "onboard" or from the Dash. I have Xubuntu here so I cannot check, but should be possible to enable it under "assistive technologies" or similar in the menu.

[image]

The panel icon let you access an extensive set of features. Never tried it (I do not have a touchscreen PC) but seems ok --- I used it sporadically to type things that could not type in a remote VNC session for layout problems.

Comment: It's already available in 14.04. Doesn't need to install

Answer (score 4):

On screen keyboard is already available in Ubuntu 14.04

If you run,`sudo apt-get install onboard`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
onboard is already the newest version
```

**To open onboard:**

Open terminal and run:`onboard`

or from dash:

[image: Imgur]