# Laptop keyboard stopped working

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, laptop

Ubuntu 14.04

I started my pc and suddenly my keyboard isn't working anymore.
Is there a possibility to debug or something?

The mouse and some of the keys still work, like changing the brightness of the screen.
Is it possible that the keyboard can be deactived somehow?

If more information is nessecery, just ask!

Thanks!

Comment: Best idea would be using a spare USB keyboard --- otherwise you can use the [onscreen keyboard](http://askubuntu.com/questions/455336/on-screen-keyboard-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts) with the mouse. Set next login without password, reboot and enter BIOS --- if it doesn't work there it's hardware (which is the most probable reason, unfortunately).

Comment: http://xkcd.com/1586/ ;-)

Answer (score 20):

try this, it my help you fix your problem:

Install the drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

If already installed, reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove xserver-xorg-input-all
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

Reboot and try again if everything is working.

Comment: Thanks! When I upgraded my Ubuntu studio to version `17.04`, my keyboard stopped working, so I logged in by ssh and installed `xserver-xorg-input-all`. Worked like a charm, thanks a lot.

Comment: I had the same issue, only the touchpad was working. The ubuntu virtual keyboard saved me, after a `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all` and a reboot, everythings came back to normal

Comment: Happened to me after switching back from windows for the first time in a while on a dual boot

Comment: Happened to me after trying to switch from Nouveau to Nvidia's proprietary driver via Linux Mint's (19.3) driver manager. The installation failed and left xorg in limbo. No mouse, no keyboard... as soon as the DE got initialized. Via Grub's Recovery Mode and these commands I was able to reset everything back to normal.

Answer (score 6):

Try this So, to fix this, go to:

System Settings → Universal Access → Typing (tab): switch off "Slow keys"

Also switch off "Enable by Keyboard" if you want to stop it happening again.

It don't know why the login screen ignores this setting, tho.

Update

I just did this again (d'oh!) which brought me back to this answer and gave me the initiative to find out what triggered it.

Apparently, if you have Enable by keyboard on and then you hold down the Shift key for eight seconds, it will enable/disable slowkeys.

This was a new setup, and I had enabled Enable by keyboard because I wanted a way to flip between touchscreen and keyboard mode easily. Might not be worth the effort, tho!

Thanks to tudor, I guess. All keyboards stopped working after login screen