# Screen freezes but mouse usable but clicks are all inactive

Tags: diagnostic

My ubuntu desktop screen is frozen.  The only thing I can do is move the mouse corsor around, but the clicks are just ignored.

Do I have to perform a hard reboot or is there a way to somehow gain control again?

I tried alt-f2 but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

I encounter the same issue almost daily running 18.04 on an HP Omen gaming desktop.  Hard power-cycle has been my only resource.

I did find a post that recommended re-installing some x11 input drivers.  Hasn't happened in the last 10 hours which is promising.

[Laptop keyboard stopped working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/688445/laptop-keyboard-stopped-working)