# Keyboard stops working whenever powered off

Tags: 20.04, keyboard

I recently installed Ubuntu (20.04 LTS) on my laptop (Asus ZenBook 13 OLED UX325). It works for the most part but I realized that whenever I use the power off option, the keyboard will not work upon restart. Basically, I need to (from another [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/688445/laptop-keyboard-stopped-working))

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

or

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove xserver-xorg-input-all
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

after using the `Screen Keyboard` to log in. I also have to be careful to push `Restart` instead of `Power Off` after written the commands in the terminal.

Needless to say, I wish to not have to do this tedious (and temporary) routine every time I `Power Off` my computer. Surely there must be a permanent solution?

Edit 1: It also appears to work if I log in using the `Screen Keyboard` after `Power Off` and then just `Restart` again. No real need for the commands above. `Power Off` is the prime suspect.

Edit 2: I do not really have to log in. After `Power Off`, I can just `Restart` before logging in, and then the keyboard works afterward. `Power Off` must be the perpetrator, no?

Comment: `dmesg | grep intel-vbtn` any output?

Comment: Thank you, @nobody. I wrote what you said but there was no output in the terminal. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry no. I thought it has to do with this.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280217/why-is-my-laptops-keyboard-screwed-up-since-kernel-5-4-0-47-till-5-8-0-20

Comment: Thank you anyways for trying to help. I am at a total loss and rather confused.

Comment: 1st > Update UEFI 2nd> Fully update the OS. Does the symptom persists?

Comment: Thank you, @ChanganAuto. The newest BIOS version is already installed (Version: 301). By fully update the OS, do you mean `sudo apt-get update` or something more elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, this solution works for me.

I am using ASUS Zenbook 13 OLED UM325S with Kubuntu 20.04

Edit file: /etc/default/grub

Replace bellow line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

WITH

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop"
```

Update bootloader

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Thank you, @Nirav. I followed your instructions and it appears to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my ASUS Zenbook 13 UM325S. (Kubuntu 20.04.3)
I tried to follow the same steps as you but had no success.

I found that there is some issue with the latest kernel version.
I just reinstall Kubuntu 18.04.5 and the issue is solve.

It's not a 100% solution but I do not want to restart every time.

I hope this will help you also.

Thanks

Comment: The question is about 20.04 and your answer addresses 18.04. Not sure this makes any sense.

Comment: Thank you, @Nirav. It could perhaps be solved (as you state) by downgrading to Ubuntu 18.04.5 but I still feel like this is something that should be fixed for future versions. I will have to live with having to restart an extra time for the time being.