# Ubuntu 16.04 virtual "On Screen" keyboard with different colors for every finger

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, onscreen-keyboard

How can I have Ubuntu's virtual "On Screen" keyboard with different colors for every finger, something about like is shown in the following thread?

By default the keyboard is only one color (dark), which makes it difficult to see which finger I should use for every key.

http://antix.freeforums.org/touchscreen-keyboard-ubuntu-onboard-on-antix-15-t5974.html

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just had to go to Onboard Settings

[On-screen keyboard in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455336/on-screen-keyboard-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Theme > Typist

:)