# "tab" on on-screen keyboard

Tags: keyboard, touchscreen

Recently I treated myself with nice add-on to my "workshop", which is Atom based Lenovo Tab 10.1.
I was able to install Ubuntu 20.04 there and I am very surprised by how it nice comes by default with touchscreen support and screen rotation, however...
why, the hell, someone could have think of not including [tab] in on-screen keyboard?!
This is "key" ingredient ;) It's like I would be missing door handle to my fridge!
Can someone please share some options I could have? like:

1. How to enable "tab" on default keyboard
2. Is there different option of on-screen keyboard than that default one?
3. Any other options anyone uses to retain autocompletion on "no physical keyboard found" devices?

Comment: You can install Onboard which comes with `tab`. https://askubuntu.com/q/455336/124466

Comment: Thanks! good direction. I installed it but it seems that it does not replace original one - that probably something I would solve sooner or later. Most important is that it appears just under active window (terminal) and things get very complicated when you change orientation while it is on screen. Makes terrible mess sticking to that window.
TL;DR
Does not work well. Unless used statically, like in "kiosk" use case.